# Word for spilt or wasted ingredients

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

When cooking, and especially baking, there’s always seasoning or flour that spills around the work area and is left out of the final dish, is there a word for these discarded ingredients?

Comment: It's usually called ***a mess***....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Waste**, **debris**, **trimmings** (if e.g. you're cutting pastry to fit a dish), ... honestly you’re as well off just finding one of those in a thesaurus and wandering around it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [**spill**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spill):

> a spilling of liquid, etc, or the amount spilt

Or can consider [**waste**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/waste):

> anything or anyone rejected as useless, worthless, or in excess of what is required

Or even [**scraps**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scrap):

> (plural) pieces of discarded food

The other answers also contain good synonyms (such as spillage and wastage, or trimmings and debris) but it really depends on the style or the exact usage. But for sure now you have a good starting point to look them up in a thesaurus and choose the best candidate for your use.

Answer (score 0):

[Spillage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/spillage) fits the term you are seeking.
[Wastage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wastage), also, but probably not as common.
Usually, I've heard *what spilled (spilt)*

> After putting the pie in the oven, she cleaned up *what had spilled* on the counter.

I think today, it would be better to use *what spilled*. *Spillage* or *wastage*
might put some specific material in the minds of some, rather than generally what spilled. We hear a lot about oil *spills* and nuclear *waste*